# Why the nested function doesn't becomes the property of the outer function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypejs

I have a code as follows:

```
function t() {
    var name = "abc";
    bar = function() {
    console.dir(this);
    console.log('bar');
 };
};
t.foo = function() {
    console.dir(this);
    this();
    console.log('bar');
};
console.dir(t);
```

It gives ouput as follows:

```
ƒ t()
foo: ƒ ()
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: "t"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: VM2091:1
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
```

So we can see that, on inspecting function t(), we don't find function "bar", but function "foo" is in the function t().My question is that why function "bar" is not a property of function t(), while function "foo" becomes a property of function t()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add properties to any JS object, including functions. So it's no surprise that `t.foo = ...` works and is displayed as a property when you log `t` to the console. The fact that the value `t.foo` points to is a function is purely incidental--it could just as well be a string, number or anything else.

A function-scoped variable like `bar` is the same as any other defined in a function body; it's not a property of the function and doesn't exist until the function is executed. `bar` declares a global variable, so it's bound to `window.bar` and persists after the function executes. If it were local, it'd be destroyed when the function returns.

You could use `foo.bar` to set a property on the function object from inside `foo`, but I can't imagine this would be useful for much.

```js
function foo() {
  foo.baz = 42;
}

foo.bar = 43;
foo();
console.log(foo.bar, foo.baz);
```

In your functions, `this` will be `window` if these functions aren't bound to any object. If you want to bind `this` to a new object and set properties on it using the function constructor, create an instance using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```js
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 42;
  this.quux = function () {};
}

Foo.prototype.baz = 43;
Foo.prototype.corge = function () {};

console.log(new Foo());
```

The distinction here is that the `this.` functions are created whenever the constructor function is called and `Foo.prototype.` variables are only defined once.

Answer (score 0):

you are using class constructors but not binding it , When using the constructor functions bind variables using this key word that's why the bar is not the property of t() . do like this

```
function t() {
var name = "abc";
this.bar = function() {
console.log(this);
console.log('bar');
   };
};
```

then make a new object 
    var newObj=new t();
now call the function from the newObj
    newObj.bar();
this should work